# cant open terminal in jupyter lab

Tags: python, terminal, jupyter-lab

Hello i use jupyter lab to code but i cannot open terminal, what it could be?
OS: Windows 7
Heres my logs:

```
        model = self.terminal_manager.create(**data)
      File "D:\lib\site-packages\jupyter_server_terminals\terminalmanager.py", l
ine 46, in create
        name, term = self.new_named_terminal(**kwargs)
      File "D:\lib\site-packages\terminado\management.py", line 380, in new_name
d_terminal
        term = self.new_terminal(**kwargs)
      File "D:\lib\site-packages\terminado\management.py", line 220, in new_term
inal
        return PtyWithClients(argv, env, cwd)
      File "D:\lib\site-packages\terminado\management.py", line 48, in __init__
        self.ptyproc = PtyProcessUnicode.spawn(**kwargs)
    AttributeError: type object 'object' has no attribute 'spawn'
[E 2023-04-07 22:29:07.903 TerminalsExtensionApp] {
      "Host": "localhost:8888",
      "Accept": "*/*",
      "Referer": "http://localhost:8888/lab",
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36
 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 YaBrowser/23.3.0.2246 Yowser/2.5 Safari/53
7.36"
```